# Hive named_struct vs map

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

So I have a table of

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | alex | 34 |
| 99 | bob | 42 |

What's the major difference between these 2?

```
SELECT TO_JSON(
      named_struct('name', name, 'age', age)
     )
FROM table
```

and

```
SELECT TO_JSON(
      map('name', name, 'age', age)
     )
FROM table
```

Comment: AFAIK they both won't work because Hive doesn't have `to_json` UDF. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF